# Create new column that carries up the last value of another column, by group

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a column "event" and would like to create a new column "ever_event" based on the values of "event." Specifically, "ever_event" will =1 in all time periods for a given ID, if "event"=1 in the last time period. "ever_event" will =0 in all time periods for a given ID, if "event"=0 in the last time period.

The new dataset would look like this:

```
id  time event   ever_event
1      0    0        1
1      1    0        1
1      2    0        1
1      3    0        1
1      4    1        1
2      0    0        0
2      1    0        0
2      2    0        0
2      3    0        0
2      4    0        0
```

Here is an example data frame. I have the "event" column, and I need a "ever_event" column.

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), event = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)), label = "HPFS_RL_100K", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: So `ever_event` doesn't track whether `event` ever happened, just whether `event` happened at the last time period? For example, if `event` equals 1 when time equals 2, but not at the last time period, `ever_event` is 0?

Comment: can you elaborate more about your question? It is not clear

Comment: @IceCreamToucan That is correct. If event=1, this will always occur in the last time period for a given ID. I would like to create a variable ever_event that =1 at all times for a given ID if that ID had event=1 their last period, and ever_event=0 otherwise. I have elaborated upon the desired output in my question in an attempt to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple data.table solution creating a new variable `ever_event` equal to the last value of `event`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, ever_event := last(event), by = id]
```

Base R solution

```
df$ever_event <- with(df, ave(event, id, FUN = function(x) tail(x, 1)))
```